# Plotting biological data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am working on a project for which I would like to plot some data on a map and I was told about QGIS by a friend that uses it. It seems pretty complex and loaded with features and I have been trying to figure it out through tutorials. But I really just need a simple plot, so I wonder if someone could help me out, or at least tell me where to look. Or maybe QGIS is not even the program I should use for this and there is something else out there.

I have biological data from about 2000 samples taken throughout Spain. Essentially what we have and want to display is each sample placed into one of 2 categories. I would like to have a map divided into the 17 autonomous communities and then I want to make a kind of heatmap of all the autonomous communities based on the percent of samples in each category. For example, if 80% of samples from Catalunya are in category 1 and 20% are in category 2, then on the map, Catalunya would be a lightish red (where 100% category 1 would be red, 100% category 2 would be blue and 50/50 would be white).

From one of the tutorials I got this data:

```
http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/data/older_data/workshop_data_2014-11.zip
```

which has this map of Spain:

```
workshop_data_2014-11/part_2/ESP_adm4.shp
```

The map is divided into cities and in the Attribute Table it has the autonomous community under NAME_1. So is there a way for me to change the map so it only divides into the different values of NAME_1? And then how can I introduce my data and color the communities accordingly?

And also, where do you obtain map files like this, in case I need to use a different one?

There are a number of other things I could plot on the map with our data, but I think if I can get this basic one down, I'll be able to figure out how to do some of the other things.

Comment: "just need a simple plot" A map is inherently more complex than a graph or chart. On top of choosing symbols, colors, and how to display data, you also have to choose a projection, often need to choose some kind of base map for context, and it helps a lot to know about how to manage relational data (think SQL databases) because how GIS data is stored and used is heavily influenced by the success of relational DBs. I'm not discouraging you from using GIS technology, but there's just so much more involved in it than plopping a few numbers based on an XY-axis. Don't expect it to be as easy.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that each thread should be limited to one specific question only. You can check our [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of mapping you can perform will depend on the level of data that you have. What kind of spatial information do you have for your 2000 biological samples?  Do you have a GPS coordinate for each sample?  It sounds like you have aggregate level data at to an administrative unit. If so, you probably want to make an indicator variable (for example, the proportion of category 1 to category 2) and you can change the colour of the map based on this proportion using the style options for the shapefile.

In order to link spatial data to your biological sample data (if the biological samples do not have GPS coordinates), you will need to do a table join ( here is a guide on table joins http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html?highlight=table%20join).  You will need to make sure that you have a value in the table of sample data that connects to the value in the shapefile. (I suggest using the code for the administrative unit).

Answer (score 1):

**For your sample data:**

Hopefully this data is in some sort of table format (xls or csv) and that each record has an associated x/y or lng/lat coordinate.  To prep this data before you load it into QGIS make sure the top row in the table has the column names and that the column names do not contain any special characters or spaces.  Finally, make sure the table is saved as a .csv file.  You may load the table into QGIS using the Add Delimited Text Layer button.  Using this feature will create a in-memory vector layer plotting the various table records as point features by the xy/lng lat columns.  Once loaded I would recommend exporting the in-memory layer to a file (like shapefile) so it is saved to disk.

**Styling the layer:**

For styling the points on the map I would suggest doing some web searches on the QGIS Style tab (accessed by right clicking on the layer selecting Properties and selecting the Style tab) for general use knowledge.  Essentially you'll want to put all your category values in one column and use the Categorized drop down renderer to symbolize each unique class value.  Also, for the heat map you could create a duplicate layer of the point layer and use the Heat Map drop down renderer.

**Linking Data**

This is commonly know as Join or Joining data.  To perform this between sample vector data and any other non vector data make sure there is a common id column between the two table columns and that it is the same data type (text to text or numeric to numeric).  For a how-to see, [Performing Table Joins](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html).